# Cookie Control Joomla Module - "no XML file"

Tags: cookies, joomla, module, joomla1.5, joomla-module

I've been trying to install the [Cookie Control](http://civicuk.com/cookie-law/cookie_configuration_v5) Joomla module, I've tried all three methods of installing (Upload, Directory, URL). Each time I try it comes back with the error

"Error! Could not find a Joomla! XML setup file in the package."

There is definitely an XML file in the root, and I have downloaded from here: 
http://www.joostrap.com/civic-cookie-control-joomla-module

Does anyone know of common errors for this or, why this maybe happening with this module?

I'm running Joomla v1.5 and have installed extensions before, but never with errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error upon installation because the module is for Joomla 2.5, not 1.5.

Im not sure if converting the extension to 1.5 will still work, but could be worth a try. From what I can see, the only file you need to change is the XML.

1. `<extension` to `<install`
2. `version="2.5"` to `version="1.5"`
3. Remove the `<config>` tags
4. Remove `<fields name="params">`
5. Change `<fieldset name="basic">` to `<params>`
6. Change all the `<field>` tags to `<param>`

Or you could have a look on the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) for 1.5 compatible extensions